# How to make linkbutton control in gridview open an new ie window

Tags: asp.net

I need  to

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="ename">
        <ItemTemplate > <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text ='<%#Eval("ID") %>' runat ="server" >
        </asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate >
        <asp:TextBox ID ="textbox1" Text='<%#Eval("name")%>'  runat ="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:LinkButton ID ="link1" Text='<%#Eval("name")%>'  runat ="server"  ></asp:LinkButton>


        </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

i have an  textbox and link button in **Edit itemtemplate**
based on the condition()

if(Text ='<%#Eval("ID") %>')

id=1 show textbox[edit item temalpate]

id=2 show link button[edit item temalpate]

id=3 show link button[edit item temalpate]

now in link button i have value `[Text='<%#Eval("name")%>']` (eg:www.stackoverflow.com ,google.com)
so that one an user clicks on the link button open a new browser window and show that website show  to open an new  browser window on the clcik  of the link button

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) control rather than a LinkButton?

eg

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
              NavigateUrl="<%#Eval('name')%>"
              Text="<%#Eval('name')%>"
              Target="_blank"
              runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: This will open the website in a new window or tab, since Target="_blank" was specified.

Comment: thanks fro teh replay  
when i use this above method. the issue is that the url in IE is opening like this: www.loaclhost:9098/admin/www.asp.net

Comment: but  www.asp.net is the value  in  my NavigateUrl="<%#Eval('name')%>"
 but in the new IE window it isopening like this
www.loaclhost:9098/admin/www.asp.net

Comment: The problem is the URL is being interpreted as begin relative to the current domain (eg localhost) and not as an absolute URL. You probably need to prefix the URLs with "http://" to make sure they get interpreted correctly by the browser.  Have not tested this syntax but try something like eg NavigateUrl="http://<%#Eval('name')%>

Answer (score 1):

You can just bind to the `OnClientClick` event of the `LinkButton`.  I would do all of this by implementing the `OnDataBinding` event for that control:

Eg:

```
// In your .aspx
<asp:LinkButton ID ="yourButton" runat="server" OnDataBinding="yourButton_DataBinding" />

//In your .cs
protected void yourButton_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    btn.Text = Eval("name");
    btn.OnClientClick = string.Format("window.open('{0}', 'yourNewWindow'); return false;", Eval("name"));
}
```

If you need more info on how the javascript window.open works check out this link:

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:HyperLink  id="hyperlink1"  NavigateUrl="<%#Eval('name')%>"  Text="<%#Eval('name')%>"  Target="_blank"  runat="server" />
```

**before  NavigateUrl we  need to the  code "http"  as shown then it  woks fine**

NavigateUrl='<%# "http://" + Eval('name')%>'

Answer (score 0):

can Add

> OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"

so on click it will call Javascript function an will open respective link in News tab.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lbnkVidTtile1" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';" runat="Server" CssClass="bodytext" Text='<%# Eval("newvideotitle") %>'  />
```