# ASP.NET: How to make linkbutton with databinder open in new window?

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I have a pdf file I get from a DataGrid and want to open it in a new window. Here is my code:

```
<ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="linkbutton1" id="TiedostoLB"  text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Tiedosto") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
```

The text-partition renders in to

```
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPH$LiitetiedotDG$ctl03$TiedostoLB','')"> file.pdf</a>
```

I tried making it a HyperLink, but NavigateUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Tiedosto") %>" renders to just the filename and not the path. How do I either fix the LinkButton to open in a new window (with some javascript:window.open() I presume) or get the HyperLink to function (which I would prefer)

Comment: Check this  post : [linkbutton-control-in-gridview-open-an-new-ie-window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853226/how-to-make-linkbutton-control-in-gridview-open-an-new-ie-window)

Comment: Where is file.pdf stored? In file system in your website? Or in a database? In memory? Somewhere else?